# Magento core_url_rewrite sporadic performance

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9, database-performance

On our production environment, I am noticing a sporadic slow performance for one of query.

```
SELECT `core_url_rewrite`.*
    FROM `core_url_rewrite`
    WHERE (request_path IN (:path?, :path?, :path?, :path?))
    AND (store_id IN(?, ?))
```

Explain Plan from production server is:

```
    id: 1
    select_type: SIMPLE
    table: core_url_rewrite
    type: range
    possible_keys: UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID,IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID
    key: UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID
    key_len: 770
    ref: NULL
    rows: 4
    Extra: Using index condition
```

Mysql version: 5.6.34. No of rows in Table: 473847. Normally it executes in less than 1ms but some of Tx as per new relic are: 8.03s, 5.35s, 3.04s, 2.97s, 1.92s in last 30 minute.

Create Table is:

```
    CREATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite` (
      `url_rewrite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rewrite Id',
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
      `id_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Id Path',
      `request_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Request Path',
      `target_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Target Path',
      `is_system` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Defines is Rewrite System',
      `options` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Options',
      `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Deascription',
      `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category Id',
      `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
      PRIMARY KEY (`url_rewrite_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID` (`id_path`,`is_system`,`store_id`),
      KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH_STORE_ID` (`target_path`,`store_id`),
      KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH` (`id_path`),
      KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
      KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` (`category_id`),
      KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` (`product_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95984103 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Url Rewrites'
```

Comment: What does `:path?` mean?  Why is that different than `?`?  Can you show us the query after substitutions have been made?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE core_url_rewrite`.

Comment: Try to get the `EXPLAIN` with values when it is slow.  And/or use the slowlog to do that task -- `long_query_time=1`, turn on slow log, wait for it to happen, then look in slowlog.

Comment: @RickJames, below is Query with substitutions: SELECT `core_url_rewrite`.* FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE (request_path IN ('newarrivals?cat=3', 'newarrivals/?cat=3', 'newarrivals', 'newarrivals/')) AND (store_id IN(0, 1))

Comment: @RickJames  Also I can't see any change in explain plan.

Comment: How many rows are returned when it takes more than a second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this problem was finally diagnosed and it is not related to mysql!
We had a low ulimit(default) of 1024. We changed it to 65535. You may check this using: **ulimit -n**.

It is one of most executed query so whenever there would be heavy rush on server, it would start waiting. It would not appear in slow-log but new relic captures it as a slow query.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a definite answer, various ramblings, and a few questions...)

The index is nearly optimal; the `EXPLAIN` says it is using the best index.  Assuming that the resultset is not returning thousands of rows, I have to go out on a limb and *guess* that this query is not the villain.

If another query is running (when this one is so slow), and that query is hitting on this table a lot (presumably with writes), then it could be slowing down this query.  The FKs are adding to the overhead.

Or, another query is flooding the buffer_pool, bumping things out of cache, leading to a sudden spike in I/O.

Or, you have a hundred connections all actively doing something, but not getting it done very fast.  (This is a case of vying for resources, each getting a 'fair' share; no one getting finished quickly.)

Turning on the slowlog with `long_query_time=1` and summarizing via `pt-query-digest` or `mydumpslow -s t` would help find the competing queries.

Check RAM size and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to see that the latter is a significant percentage of the former.  (If it is small, then that *could* lead to the I/O scenario.)

As an aside, `KEY(product_id)` is redundant with the 3-column key starting with `product_id`.  Redundant keys waste time on `INSERT`.

Another aside:  You have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` that has reached 95M, that's 140/th of the limit (4B).  Do the math - when will you run out?  Meanwhile, there are only 0.47M rows in the table.  This implies the use of `REPLACE` (which may have an better replacement) or some other action that 'burns' ids.  Please elaborate on your `INSERTs`.

One solution (to the above paragraph) may be to get rid of `url_rewrite_id` and promote one of the `UNIQUE` keys to PK.  (It is vary rare for a table to have 3 meaningful unique keys.)  There are pros to the promotion, but there are significant cons, since either `UNIQUE` includes a `VARCHAR(255)`.  So, I am not going to recommend it *yet*.

Promoting the key that *this* query is using would speed up *this* query.

Comment: Thanks for many insights. It is expected to return only 2-3 results. I can confirm it from New relic slow traces as well. The table is written only once a day for 10-15 minutes for new entries. I have confirmed it from ibd file as well. It is highly used table with 700-800cpm as per new relic., it is core magento table, so I shall not try to change much code. Current Ram in Machine: 60 GB, innodb_buffer_pool 37G. DB size is < 30G. How can I check another query is flooding the buffer_pool, bumping things out of cache, leading to a sudden spike in I/O.

Comment: Hmmm...  Numbers look good.  If the entire data and indexes are less than 37G, then my theory about being bumped out of cache does not apply.

Comment: Any other hint, this query is really annoying in otherwise really good looking application numbers. Also I checked auto_increment numbers, it may be due to historic truncation and reinserts. current growth rate is pretty negligible and truncation not happening.

Comment: Where did you get 8.03s, 5.35s, etc?  Would the same source record a long running query at about the same time?  (I am not familiar with relic.)

Comment: new relic is performance monitoring tool. No there is no other slow query at that time. Actually other than this all queries are getting executed <200ms. even average for this table is ~80ms which could have been much lower without these aberrations.